# Releasing OrbitControls in threejs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, three.js, durandal

I have a Single Page Application with a lot of stuff in it, using durandal. On one page I have a link that leads to a different page where 3d model is rendered. OrbitControls are used to make model turn etc. That takes away my default left click and right click. After leaving that page, it still keeps mouse bindings and my left click and right click become useless for some uses like - selecting an  tag meaning that input tags cannot be accessed again.

I could release bindings and reset them if I knew how. There is a deactivate function which is called when that 3d window is closed, but I have no idea what piece of code to write there. Any help would be extremely useful. I doubt any code will be of any use so I won't put any.

Thank you!

Due to request, here is simplified viewmodel:

```
define(['services/logger'], function (logger) {
    var vm = {
        attached: attached
    };
    return vm;
    function attached(view) {
        var camera, cameraTarget, scene, renderer, controls;
        init();
        animate();
        function init() {
            ...
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
            ...
        }
        function animate(){...}
        function render(){...}
     }
}
```

View is extremely complicated, but pasted here in full:

```
<div id="canvasDiv" style="overflow: hidden; width:100%; height:100%">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it would probably be helpful to include your code to setup OrbitControls (I'm not familiar with it).

The best approach to this whole issue would probably be to write a Knockout custom binding (google if you don't know them). A custom binding is a great place to abstract away DOM manipulation, in your case for setting up OrbitControls.

Let's assume that you have a div on which you set up OrbitControls. You could then do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="myOrbitControlsBinding: { someSetting: true; someOtherSetting: false }"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myOrbitControlsBinding = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var settings = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        setupOrbitControlsOnElement(element, settings); // This should be your setup code for OrbitControls
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            // Here, you should unbind the event handlers for mouse clicks. How you do this depends on how OrbitControls sets them up. Please refer to their documentation for this. Maybe there is a generic dispose function?
            disposeOrbitControls(element);
        });
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Ah, I didn't realize you use Three. I've quickly scanned their documentation to see if they use some sort of input module that captures the events. They don't seem to. Which probably means that some where in your code, there is the keyword 'addEventListener' (search for it). This will be where the events are caught.

Your view probably has a viewmodel attached to it since you're using durandal. Inside the viewmodel, add a 'deactivate' method (and return it). In this method, you need to remove the event listener again. You probably already guessed it, but the method is called removeEventListener (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener for an explanation)

I still highly recommend that you create a custom binding to setup Three. This will give you much more control over creation/deletion than you might have now. If you don't want to, make sure that Three is initialized inside the viewmodel as well, in the activate method.

Let me know if that helped, otherwise some viewmodel / three init code would be helpful.

Comment: Updated question with simplified viewmodel. I only started using Three few days ago so can't really answer in a lot of detail what is going on. I don't need any real bindings due to the fact I'm making just a preview of a model, not an editor.

Comment: Updated my post above as well

Comment: I looked a bit further, I re-read your question and saw you already have a deactivate callback. I googled OrbitControls. Is this what you're using? http://tileableart.com/code/natureof/js/three/js/controls/OrbitControls.js

Cause I scanned that file for addEventListener. There's six occurences. You need to remove those event listeners again in your deactivate callback, and your mouse clicks (and other events) should be yours again :)

Comment: That is the one. I just changed my initialization of Orbit controls:
`controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, myDomElement);` where `myDomElement` is div in html. That way only in that div are controls given to OrbitControls. Thanks! You made me look thoroughly through that code and then I realized how to do it ;)

Comment: Even better. I overlooked the possibility to provide an element in the constructor. Glad to have helped, even though you figured out the best fix yourself ;)